# urllib.request is super slow at night

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I just startet to gather data from coingecko and I realized that the download of the json file needs longer at night. It took ~0.1 per 200 bytes or so, but at night I ended up with ~42.1 seconds per file.

The interesting thing is, when I just check for google or other websites it took ~21.1 seconds.

Is there any reason for this behavior? I thought a lot about that, but haven't found anything.

```
import urllib.request as req
import time
t0 = time.time()
with req.urlopen(
    "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/market_chart/range?vs_currency=eur&from=1422403200&to=1422489600") as response:
     print(time.time() - t0)
     # 42.1 seconds

t0 = time.time()
with req.urlopen("https://www.google.com") as response:
     print(time.time() - t0)
     # 21.1 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not to do with the urllib library or anything todo with your code. It will judt be due to a slow internet connection.

Comment: At first, thanks for you answer, but that can not be the case. I do not have any losses regarding up/download rates. Additional to this: During the day I have a mean duration of x, while on night I have a mean duration of 21+x  or 42+x if I am downloading something. It is weird that every website I try to open with urllib.request need exactly this 21+x seconds time.

Comment: Check you don't have anything where your cide sleeps in there.